# Is it correct sentence? "It doesn’t make sense for he who’s not planning to stay here for a longer time."

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If not, please help me correct it.
It's from an experience of mine.

One of my friends wants to stay at my home a little bit longer and I just complained in my mind.

> It doesn’t make sense for he/him/someone who’s not planning to stay
>   here for a longer time.

Can I use for subject to "It" while I want to use "He" in the same sentence? like "It was he who"

Comment: Can I use for subject to "It" while I want to use "He" in the same sentence? like It was he who ~~~?

Comment: Add that to your question. Give us some context: where is this from? What are you trying to ask? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: The sentence is currently ambiguous but not necessarily grammatically incorrect. (1) When you say "It doesn't make sense," *what* doesn't make sense? His stay alone or something else (for example, painting the bedroom his favorite color? (2) When you say "here," do you mean your home or the general area?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds much better: "It doesn't make sense for anyone who isn't planning to stay here much longer."

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Answer (score 0):

Using "it" and "he" in the construct:

> "**It** was **he** who ..."

is perfectly fine.

---

Regarding the main question, it seems grammatically correct, but it is too long and complex, unnecessarily. I would use:

> Why wouldn't he leave (at once)?

or:

> Why is he still here?

Of course, my thoughts might be a bit more complex than that, but I will not write here any bad words ;)